# How to design a permanent vaccine to cholera using CRISPR?

Tags: human-biology, dna, gene-expression, crispr, gene-editing

I know that *Vibrio Cholerae* infects the body through the GM1 ganglioside. So, would it be possible to engineer a CRISPR gene editing tool to prevent *Vibrio Cholerae* from getting into our cells?

Specifically, would it be possible to insert a piece of DNA into our genes that allow the synthesis of cholera toxin-suspressing protein shown  [here](https://dx.doi.org/10.1093%2Fglycob%2Fcwv080) ([Pubmed link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4672148/)).

The reason I ask this question is that there are obvious benefits to being immune to cholera from birth. While I'm definitely not planning on being the next He Jiankui, I find the prospect of such a vaccine highly intriguing.

Edit: changed link because I posted the wrong link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, would it be possible to engineer a CRISPR gene editing tool to
>   prevent Vibrio Cholerae from getting into our cells?

Vibrio Cholerae doesn't get into our cells.

Did you observe that your paper has no in vitro experiments?

It's going to be tough to get a cell to transcribe and translate something so small, and will the peptide work if it needs a leader sequence to be exported out of the cell?

Its much much easier to break a gene in every cell than to add a new gene and have just a small subset of cell types make large quantities of that gene product.